# changing the bahaviour of the command \cite when the bibitem is not already defined

Tags: citing

When I use `\cite[p. 114]{Smith}` and the bibitem `Smith` is not defined in the bibliography, one gets the warning `there were unresolved citations`. Consequently an output something like `[?, p. 114]` appears after compilation. Is it possible to make a change in the definition of the command `\cite` in such a way that when the bibitem has not already been defined,  `\cite[p. 114]{Smith}`  produces `[Smith, p. 114]`.

I do not use an specific package. The document is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite[p. 114]{Smith}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{John}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer to your question depends importantly on whether or not you've loaded any citation management packages, e.g., `cite`, `natbib`, `harvard`, and `biblatex`. Please advise if you're using one of these packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the internal command. Be aware that this can break if you load packages which change the cite command like natbib, jurabib etc. T1-encoding is needed for the underscore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries \detokenize\expandafter{\@citeb}}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\cite[p. 114]{Smith}

\cite[p. 114]{Smith_blub}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{John}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]